# jQuery AJAX request yielding 405 error despite knowing the method is right

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using an API that someone else in my company made, and one of the endpoints he's created accepts GET requests with an access key header provided from another endpoint. I use the following jQuery AJAX to call it:

```
      $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: 'http://myapi.com',
        crossDomain: true,
        headers: {
          "token": data.AccessKey
        }

      })
```

In Chrome, this returns 2 error messages in the console:

```
OPTIONS http://myapi.com  jquery.min.js:4k.cors.a.crossDomain.send jquery.min.js:4n.extend.ajax jquery.min.js:4(anonymous function) (index):69j jquery.min.js:2k.fireWith jquery.min.js:2x jquery.min.js:4(anonymous function) jquery.min.js:4

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myapi.com. Invalid HTTP status code 405 (index):1
```

In Firefox I get a different error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://myapi.com. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

But we enabled CORS on the API server (we were getting that message on Chrome, too, before we did) so I don't know why it's saying that.

I know that this endpoint is expecting a GET request. If I send this request with no headers at all, it returns a 200 status and a response containing the expected "You need a key to access this information". If we try it on hurl.it, the GET request with a valid key as a header returns the expected results.

Because of CORS, it's running the pre-flight OPTIONS request, which I think is what's giving the 405 error, but shouldn't the server accept OPTIONS methods? How do we ensure this method is accepted? Is there something else going on that I'm not catching? CORS is a new concept to me so feel free to ELI5 your answers.

Comment: Is your page being viewed via file:// or http:// protocol? Chrome won't do cross domain requets if host page is file://

Comment: The server should accept an OPTIONS request, but it looks like it does not do so.  This is something you should probably bring up with the person in charge of the API.

Comment: Check request/response headers.

Comment: @Matt I'm viewing my page via localhost, but I looked at ways of getting around that issue. Plus I'm having similar problems on Firefox.

Comment: @AaronDufour I did bring it up with him, but he says it doesn't seem like he is able to directly allow OPTIONS requests. Is this something I should call him out on? Or is there something specific he needs to do?

Comment: @RuslanasBalčiūnas 
Request headers:

    OPTIONS /api/random/ HTTP/1.1
Host: myapi.com
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://localhost:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.122 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, token
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

Comment: Response headers: HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Allow: GET
Content-Length: 76
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST
Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=5e283e5d036e634a6d7c3deef54c6fc246aa5127e8bdc9813dce947949311c2e;Path=/;Domain=api.epirecommends.com
Date: Thu, 04 Dec 2014 16:24:39 GMT
ConsoleSearchEmulationRendering



Preserve log
.

Comment: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET" OPTIONS not allowed.

Comment: http://eugeneagafonov.com/post/38312919044/iis-options-cors-aspnet-webapi-en this might help. I know nothing about IIS.